# I'm having trouble with a loop in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing code to search every cell in a range. I want to find all the values of 2 or less characters (e.g. "12" "ab") and then delete those cells. I have it sort of working, but the VBA code is running really slow and only works for 1 column per run. So it won't find everything, just find it in column A, then the code will end without moving onto column B.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub test2()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 524
    For j = 1 To 12
        If Len(Cells(i, j)) <= 2 Then
            Cells(i, j).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a range, so `set r=range("a1:l524)` and then use for each cell in r, then do the same, `if len(r.value)<=2 then cell.delete`

Comment: Worth noting that you're working column by column then row by row.  When the code has finished on row 524, it won't move onto any other column; it's looping as a `for each row..for each column in row` type loop

Comment: If you delete a cell and shift it to the left, the cell in the column to the right will move into its place. This means that cell will not be scanned as you code has already "processed" the cell at the I/j coordinates

Comment: @Dave is there ant other way I can write the loop? I'm still new to VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = 1 To 524
            For j = 12 To 1 Step -1
                If Len(Cells(i, j)) <= 2 Then
                    Cells(i, j).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! this worked perfect! The "step -1" must have done the trick. Thank you! Also you read my mind about the screenupdating = false thing.

Comment: @AutomateMyJob  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Use a range, so set `r=range("a1:l524)` and then use `for each cell in r`, then do the same, `if len(r.value)<=2 then cell.delete`

Answer (score -1):

Define the range you want to check and execute the control for each cell of the range

```
Public Sub test2()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1:X52")
        If Len(cell) <= 2 Then
            cell.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It should do the work

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing has changed. It still only does one column then ends without moving on the next column.